# Getting "http///" in address bar

Tags: watir

"URL.txt" file contains "www.google.com". the puts shows the value in the console. But after launching IE, in address bar it shows "[http:///]" and program tarminates.
Here is my Watir code.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
File.open("URL.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
  puts line
end
a = Watir::Browser.new
a.goto '#{line}'
```

am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking IE to go the url `#{line}`. If you do this manually, IE automatically goes to `http:///`.

You have 2 issues:

1. When you do `'#{line}'`, the single quotes mean that there is no string interpolation - ie you get what you see. To have the string interpolation, you need double quotes - `"#{line}"`. However, in this case, you could simply do `line` (ie line is already a string).
2. Assuming you fixed issue 1, the next problem is that `line` is undefined in `a.goto "#{line}"`. You have only defined it within the File.open block. It is no longer available when you get to the `a.goto`.

Assuming that the script is meant to visit each url in the file, you probably meant to do:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
File.open("URL.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
  puts line
  a = Watir::Browser.new
  a.goto line
end
```

Or, if you were to visit each page using the same browser:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
a = Watir::Browser.new
File.open("URL.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
  puts line
  a.goto line
end
```